# What is the best approach for multi-regional community

Tags: community, multi-regional

We currently have a community. Previously, we use different domain names for US, AU, and NZ, but all these redirect to only 1 community. But recently, NZ and US wants to have slightly different content. They want to use the same look and feel, but the items that are shown in the site, as well as some links and information, they want to customize it to better suit them.

My question is, how should we implement this? Should we create 2 other communities that are just copy-paste versions of the original community, with a slightly tweaked content? Or should we add logic in the code to be able to determine whether we should show US-specific or AU-specific or NZ-specific content? Or is there another approach we're missing?

I know this will be subjective and is likely to be closed, but I don't know any other place to discuss an architecture like this.

Comment: Have you tried using audiences in community builder?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Audience and Page variations to have a different communityexperience for different types of users. You can select individual Components dropped on community page to be hidden or shown depending upon the audience criteria or you can have multiple page variations of a single page shown or hidden to different types of community users.
Use following link to understand how to setup audiences in lightning communities. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null
Page Variations will be handy if all contents of page are going to be different. refer here for page variations setup https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_manage.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null .You can create a completely different page using the same page URL. if only few sections of the page has to be different, you can use Audiences on individual Components on a common page.